# shark failing to compile: static assert failed _DISABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, shark-ml

I followed the installation guide with Visual Studio 2022 as described [here](https://www.shark-ml.org/sphinx_pages/build/html/rest_sources/installation.html). I am able to clone from git and then use cmake to produce a VS2022 sln file. However, when I attempt to build that solution in VS2022, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C2338   static_assert failed: 'You've instantiated
> std::aligned_storage<Len, Align> with an extended alignment (in other
> words, Align > alignof(max_align_t)). Before VS 2017 15.8, the member
> "type" would non-conformingly have an alignment of only
> alignof(max_align_t). VS 2017 15.8 was fixed to handle this correctly,
> but the fix inherently changes layout and breaks binary compatibility
> (*only* for uses of aligned_storage with extended alignments). Please
> define either (1) _ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE to acknowledge that
> you understand this message and that you actually want a type with an
> extended alignment, or (2) _DISABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE to
> silence this message and get the old non-conforming
> behavior.'    shark   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\type_traits   987

I am seeing this error 209 times which is also the number of projects in the cmake generated sln. When I double click on one of those errors, I am taken to a file called `type_traits` where I see the following code:

```
#ifndef _DISABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE
    static_assert(_Always_false<_Aligned>,
        "You've instantiated std::aligned_storage<Len, Align> with an extended alignment (in other "
        "words, Align > alignof(max_align_t)). Before VS 2017 15.8, the member \"type\" would "
        "non-conformingly have an alignment of only alignof(max_align_t). VS 2017 15.8 was fixed to "
        "handle this correctly, but the fix inherently changes layout and breaks binary compatibility "
        "(*only* for uses of aligned_storage with extended alignments). "
        "Please define either "
        "(1) _ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE to acknowledge that you understand this message and "
        "that you actually want a type with an extended alignment, or "
        "(2) _DISABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE to silence this message and get the old non-conforming "
        "behavior.");
#endif // !_DISABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE
```

Seems like I may need to define `_DISABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE`. Please say what is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Shark has left it to the person compiling the it to choose weather to define `_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE` or `_DISABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE`. I chose the latter.